# Ubuntu Linux on Lenovo B575

Tags: lenovo

I am thinking of buying a laptop, namely the Lenovo B575, which has the following:
- AMD Dual Core E2-2000 (1.75 GHz) with 1 MB L2 cache
- AMD Radeon HD 7340 shared memory
Can anybody tell me if there is an Ubuntu version compatible with the above model?

Thanks,
 Nick

Answer (score 0):

I think the normal Ubuntu version (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/) should work. Check out the Ubuntu system requirements at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements, as far as i can see, your laptop has the required features to work with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Look for Ubuntu Certification for your model number on Google. An Ubuntu certified laptop should run any Linux out the box.